# Changing animation's duration dynamically in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, watchos

I'm trying to change animation's duration while it animates. I've got two properties - `isAnimating` which determines whether animation should be running or not and `duration`. There is one view that is being animated, button which toggles `isAnimating` and Slider which is bound to duration state. When animation is playing and I change value using Slider, duration doesn't change. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isAnimating = false
    @State var duration = 2.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 2.0 : 1.0)
                .animation(
                    isAnimating ?
                        Animation.easeOut(duration: duration).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) :
                        .default
            )
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(
                action: { self.isAnimating.toggle() },
                label: { Text("Tap") }
            )
            
            Spacer()
            
            Slider(value: $duration, in: (0.1 ... 5.0))
                .padding([.horizontal], 20.0)
                .padding([.bottom], 50.0)
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried different approaches but there was always some problem with it (animated view flickering for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you add a .repeatForever() modifier to your animation the animation will run as the name implies forever (with the given parameters). The only possibility is to stop the animation and "rerun" a new animation with a changed "duration" value.

Comment: So... how do you stop and rerun a new animation with different properties?